# Play Framework: Error during sbt execution: java.io.IOException: Permission denied

Tags: playframework, sbt, typesafe-activator, xubuntu

(my system is Xubuntu 14.04 . I did the same installation as on Unity 14.04 on which the problem didn't occur. But i can't change back the OS due to memory issues.)

I got a problem using the 'Play Framework' via Activator.

I get the error message above when running any 'activator' command, like 'activator ui' or 'activator eclipsify'. However 'activator -help' is working without problems.

I already changed all the permissions so that 'user' (which is me) has 'Read & Write' access. I also tried to reinstall it by deleting '.activator' and '.sbt' but it didn't help anything.

Is there anything else I can try out, or a way to contact someone from the 'Play Framework'?

Comment: any luck resolving this? I'm having this prob too right now

Comment: No, I wasn't able to fix this problem. Maybe switching DE's can fix this problem (as it only appeared to me with Xubuntu), but I greatly doubt it.

Comment: I had to destroy all references to a /target directory which were hidden in other folders, once I deleted these the permission were corrected. Also checking out the code and rebuilding from source, brand new, worked for me too. Hope this helps